Is it permissible to write non Muslim fictional stories?
I am a Muslim author...I write stories but my characters are non Muslims...also i don't write intimate moments .. sometimes just a little bit of romance...like hug and pecks .. mostly my all reader are non Muslims...also i told them not to encourage by anything which is included in the stories ... So can you please tell me is it permissible to write it or it's Haram? I want to know... sometime there is dating also..means before marriage as it is normal in non Muslims..so please can you clarify it ..thank you
